# Rails 4 app getting errors uploading via Amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can upload images via the paperclip gem to  localhost but when i do this on heroku i get errors

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 801ms
ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):
app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:29:in `create'
ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):
app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

I ran heroku config which shows everything has been setup - bucket , id & access key and looking
at Amazon s3 - images have been saved in the past but now i get errors.

listings controller

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listings = Listing.all
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /listings/new
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

      if @listing.save
        redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.'
      else
        render action: 'new' 
      end
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1.json
  def update

      if @listing.update(listing_params)
         redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.'
      else
        render action: 'edit'
      end
  end

  # DELETE /listings/1
  # DELETE /listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @listing.destroy
      redirect_to listings_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :description, :image)
    end
end
```

listing.rb

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

config.production

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make an application.yml file in the config folder? Here is an example: https://github.com/codeprimate/mylibrary/blob/master/config/application.yml.example

You need to put your bucket information in there.

Comment: no i pushed this straight to heroku using the heroku config commands